# Give an image in MVC 4 project folder path for string attachmentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"";

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm sending email when user want to recover password

All of this forgot password function working properly

Here that code snippet to give image path in that method

```
// create the INLINE attachment
 string attachmentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/hec-logo.png";
```

so default path is taking as `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\` I want to change this to my mvc 4 project images folder path

which is `~\Test_Project\Images`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the server path:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
```

Comment: `string attachmentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");` like this ?

Comment: What you need exactly is this :
`string attachmentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/")+@"/hec-logo.png";`

Comment: `string attachmentPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");` this one also worked however ur correct ! thanks lots